# django - use urlpattern name in forms.ValidationError()

Tags: django, django-urls

I have the following statement.

```
raise forms.ValidationError({'product_type':
    [mark_safe('Product type <a href="/group/detail/%d/">N/A already exists</a> for this combination.' % na[0].product_group.id) ]})
```

This app has the following named url

```
url(r'^detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ProductGroupDetail.as_view(), name='group_detail'),
```

Is there a way to use `{%url 'group_detail' %}` format in the href rather than hard-coded urls?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use result of [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) function:

```
url = reverse('group_detail', kwargs={'pk': na[0].product_group.id})
[mark_safe('Product type <a href="%s">N/A already exists</a> for this combination.' % url ]})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `reverse`:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

url = reverse('group_detail', args=[pk])
```

For a detail view, I recommend to implement `get_absolute_url` on the model. This method name is a Django convention. The Django Admin will test for it and link to it if present.

```
# models.py
class ProductGroupModel(Model):

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('group_detail', args=[self.pk])
```

You can then easily use it with a model instance:

```
'Product type <a href="{url}">N/A already exists</a> for this combination.'.format(
    url=obj.get_absolute_url())
```